# Vanilla Java - Generate Swagger JSON

Tags: java, swagger, generator, documentation, openapi

I have a vanilla Java project (no frameworks). And here is a simple Java class.

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class Person {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
}
```

I want to generate Open API JSON for the specified classes during the build time. For example, I could write a unit test that calls the required functions and write the result JSON file to the `build` folder.

I searched the Internet and I haven't found solution for a regular Java project. In the [Swagger-Core](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core) repository there are examples for JAX-RS and Spring Boot projects. The thing is that I don't have any endpoints. There are just some data classes that I want to document.

Has anybody solved similar problem? What is the possible approach?